# Yarn install hang but npm works with the same config

Tags: npm, yarnpkg

When I try to do a `yarn install`, it hangs. With npm all works fine.

My .npmrc file:

```
strict-ssl=false
registry=https://[url]/artifacts/repo/npm/
```

My .yarnrc file:

```
strict-ssl false
registry "https://[url]/artifacts/repo/npm/"
```

`yarn --verbose` output:

```
verbose 2.703 Performing "GET" request to "[url]/repo/npm/@company/coco.tools-nodejs-lite/-/@company/coco.tools-nodejs-lite-1.0.1.tgz".
[###---] 3/6
```

I have a private ssl registry and I've seen that when I do a `npm install` all packages are download from https url, but when I do a `yarn install`, the packages are download from http. If I delete strict-ssl false in Yarn doesn't work either. If I delete strict-ssl=false in npm I obtain this error:

```
...tgz failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

The registry doesn't work with http request, it only works with https, and when I try to access the registry by browser I obtain a SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER, but I think that this isn't the problem. The problem is that Yarn's requests are done to http instead https but if I put strict-ssl=true and request are done to https Yarn hangs too...

Can anyone help me?